# HP E3800 switch to switch LACP connection dropping

Tags: switch, hp, trunk, lacp

I have a problem with 2 sets of stacked (2 switches in each stack) HP E3800 48 port switches.  One set of stacked switches per rack for a total of 4 switches.  I have a 4 port static LACP connection between these two sets of switches with the link spanning each switch to eliminate switch failure.  The config is very simple and only has two VLANs passing through this connection.  One is tagged and the other untagged.  I have spanning tree turned off.  The problem I have is that every once in a while one of the ports will go off-line and drop or block all traffic for about 1 minute.

Here are the entries from one of the switch's logs from today;

```
I 08/30/12 15:40:03 00435 ports: ST1-CMDR: port 2/47 is Blocked by LACP
I 08/30/12 14:28:19 00076 ports: ST1-CMDR: port 2/48 in Trk1 is now on-line
I 08/30/12 14:28:18 00435 ports: ST1-CMDR: port 2/48 is Blocked by LACP
I 08/30/12 14:28:11 00077 ports: ST1-CMDR: port 2/48 in Trk1 is now off-line
```

The problem happened at the 15:40 entry.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?  Is there a documented issue with switch-to-switch LACP links with HP?  Or is there a better way to connect switches across racks?

Comment: What happens in the other switches logs for the same time?

Comment: The exact same entry(ies) with the corresponding ports on that switch.

Comment: HP support has told me that they aren't experts with stacking their switches and are working through learning these as problems come up. Unbelievable! Anyone who reads this: DO NOT BUY THESE HP SWITCHES AND SET THEM UP WITH THE STACKING CABLE. We have the J9576A model with the stacking module and cables.